# Does Google crawl HTTPS Links?

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

I have a secured site. Will Google (and other search engines) crawl the pages on the site?

Comment: I had a technician from Godaddy tell me that HTTPS would make a page "un-crawlable". I thought that that was weird because I work in SEO, and I've never heard of that. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Google will index both HTTP and HTTPS pages. It's evident if you try to use search, although I can't seem to find confirmation from any "official" source at the moment.

Comment: Here's a reference: [In this table listing Googlebot UAs](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943), notice that the table header says "HTTP(S) requests".

Comment: Regarding the article you linked to in your update: quite frankly, that is **absolute garbage**.  The author makes no sound technical argument (in fact, I'd argue he misunderstands how HTTPS works), and he's essentially just complaining about FIFA's misconfigured setup.  That article does not represent best practices (or even good ideas).

Comment: @josh3736, I think you right. One good reason for not allowing HTTPS indexing of your site is to prevent possible SEO issues, but that article didn't cover it so I removed the link.

Comment: What SEO issues could arise?  I'd hope that Google would be smart enough to know that `http://site/page` is the same as `https://site/page` and not ding you for duplicate content.

Comment: If you don't use rel="canonical" in links on your site, you may (and this changes quickly as search engines algorithms improve) run into canonicalization problems.

Comment: That "official word" is for the Google Search Appliance, not for Googlebot.