# Index and crawl data with HTTPS urls

Tags: web-crawler, google-search-console

My website is kind of public (user can view without ***signing*** in)  + private (user have to sign-in to use).

So my question is, how the Google crawler supposed to know that my website is private (URL with **https**). And also I want to crawl that content and index my all ULRs with HTTPS.

Is there any option available to support HTTPS urls with **Google webmaster tools**. And if there is a option to support these URLs then I am wondering how the Google crawler is going to access my web-content without signing-in. So guys share your thoughts and Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google crawl HTTPS Links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980613/does-google-crawl-https-links)

Answer (score 0):

Google is able to crawl and understand HTTPS URLs just as it is able to crawl and understand HTTP URLs. That being said, Google can't sign-in to your website, so anything behind sign-in will not be visible to Google.